# Segmentation fault caused by sem_getvalue()

Tags: c, process, synchronization, semaphore

I'm writin a small piece of code in C using semaphores included in , but I can't go on because on the sem_getvalue line I always obtain a segmentation fault. Can someone explain me why? Thx

EDIT: I compiled with gcc -lpthread -lrt -l c

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3
#define FILENAME "resource.txt"
#define SEM_PROC "/semname"

int main(){
    FILE* f = fopen(FILENAME, "w");
    sem_t* proc_semaphore = sem_open(SEM_PROC, O_CREAT, "0777", 0);
    if (proc_semaphore == SEM_FAILED) {
        printf("[FATAL ERROR] Could not open the named semaphore\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Sem created\n");
    int* current= malloc(sizeof(int)); *current = -N;
    sem_getvalue(proc_semaphore, current);
    printf("current value: %d\n:", *current);
```

Comment: don't cast the result of  malloc

Comment: `"0777"` is definitely wrong (remove the quotation marks), but that shouldn't have caused a crash. And you didn't include stdlib.h, which the compiler would have complained about if you hadn't cast the result of malloc (don't cast the result of malloc), but if that was going to be a problem it should have caused a crash on the `*current = -N` line, not the `sem_getvalue`.  And you didn't check whether `sem_open` succeeded.  That's probably the most important error.

Comment: Ok thanks I realized the error was in the sem_open function. But now I can't understand why sem_open always fails.

Comment: (Also I don't see why you don't just use `int current = -3; sem_getvalue(proc_semaphore, &current);`)

Comment: Are you printing out `strerror(errno)` when sem_open fails?  You should always do that when a system call fails.

Comment: Yeah that was my previous version of the code, but then I tried to use malloc for no reason at all :)

Comment: Your revised code still has several bugs: (1) you need `#include <fcntl.h>`; (2) change `"0777"` to `0777`; (3) change `printf("[FATAL ERROR] ...")` to `fprintf(stderr, "[FATAL ERROR] sem_open %s: %s\n", SEM_PROC, strerror(errno))` (and add `string.h` and `errno.h` to the includes).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say definitely what's going wrong but I try.

- malloc can return **NULL** if this function cannot allocate memory for you for some reason. This may lead to SEGFAULT. I suggest replace your *int* * with simple *int* variable:

  ```
  int current = -N;
  sem_getvalue(sem,&current);
  ```
- I suggest using perror() function instead of printf for error handle because it prints human readable message with error details:

  ```
  sem_t* proc_semaphore = sem_open(SEM_PROC, O_CREAT, "0777", 0);
  if (proc_semaphore == SEM_FAILED) {
      perror("ERROR:");// e.g. "ERROR: Permission denied" or similar
      exit(1);
  }
  ```
- You defined *SEM_PROC* as *"/semname* which leades to "Permission denied" error while creating semaphore for me. You should define name which can be used by regular user (e.g. "semname").

Comment: Your other advice is sound, but `sem_open("/foo")` *does not* create a file in the root directory, even though it looks like it.  It actually has unspecified behavior if you *don't* use a name with a leading slash (and no internal slashes).  I don't know why you're getting "Permission denied".